# How do I handle an accented character on a batch database import in Python and Postgres

Tags: python, django, postgresql

When running a batch import script in Python (openblock), I'm getting the following invalid byte sequence for encoding "UTF8": 0xca4e error for an accented character:

It shows up as:
GRAND-CH?NE, COUR DU

But is actually "GRAND-CHÊNE, COUR DU"

What is the best way to handle this? Ideally I'd like to keep the accented character. I suspect I need to encode it somehow?

**Edit**: the ? is actually supposed to be Ê. Also note that the variable is coming from an ESRI Shapefile. When I try davidcrow's solution, I get "Unicode not supported", because presumably the strings that don't have accented characters are already Unicode strings.

Here's the ESRIImporter code I'm using:

```
from django.contrib.gis.gdal import DataSource

class EsriImporter(object):
    def __init__(self, shapefile, city=None, layer_id=0):
        print >> sys.stderr, 'Opening %s' % shapefile
        ds = DataSource(shapefile)

        self.layer = ds[layer_id]
        self.city = "OTTAWA" #city and city or Metro.objects.get_current().name
        self.fcc_pat = re.compile('^(' + '|'.join(VALID_FCC_PREFIXES) + ')\d$')

    def save(self, verbose=False):
        alt_names_suff = ('',)
        num_created = 0
        for i, feature in enumerate(self.layer):
            #if not self.fcc_pat.search(feature.get('FCC')):
            #    continue
            parent_id = None
            fields = {}
            for esri_fieldname, block_fieldname in FIELD_MAP.items():
                value = feature.get(esri_fieldname)
                #print >> sys.stderr, 'Looking at %s' % esri_fieldname

                if isinstance(value, basestring):
                    value = value.upper()
                elif isinstance(value, int) and value == 0:
                    value = None
                fields[block_fieldname] = value
            if not ((fields['left_from_num'] and fields['left_to_num']) or
                    (fields['right_from_num'] and fields['right_to_num'])):
                continue
            # Sometimes the "from" number is greater than the "to"
            # number in the source data, so we swap them into proper
            # ordering
            for side in ('left', 'right'):
                from_key, to_key = '%s_from_num' % side, '%s_to_num' % side
                if fields[from_key] > fields[to_key]:
                    fields[from_key], fields[to_key] = fields[to_key], fields[from_key]
            if feature.geom.geom_name != 'LINESTRING':
                continue
            for suffix in alt_names_suff:
                name_fields = {}
                for esri_fieldname, block_fieldname in NAME_FIELD_MAP.items():
                    key = esri_fieldname + suffix
                    name_fields[block_fieldname] = feature.get(key).upper()
                    #if block_fieldname == 'postdir':
                        #print >> sys.stderr, 'Postdir block %s' % name_fields[block_fieldname]


                if not name_fields['street']:
                    continue
                # Skip blocks with bare number street names and no suffix / type
                if not name_fields['suffix'] and re.search('^\d+$', name_fields['street']):
                    continue
                fields.update(name_fields)
                block = Block(**fields)
                block.geom = feature.geom.geos
                print repr(fields['street'])
                print >> sys.stderr, 'Looking at block %s' % unicode(fields['street'], errors='replace' )

                street_name, block_name = make_pretty_name(
                    fields['left_from_num'],
                    fields['left_to_num'],
                    fields['right_from_num'],
                    fields['right_to_num'],
                    '',
                    fields['street'],
                    fields['suffix'],
                    fields['postdir']
                )
                block.pretty_name = unicode(block_name)
                #print >> sys.stderr, 'Looking at block pretty name %s' % fields['street']

                block.street_pretty_name = street_name
                block.street_slug = slugify(' '.join((unicode(fields['street'], errors='replace' ), fields['suffix'])))
                block.save()
                if parent_id is None:
                    parent_id = block.id
                else:
                    block.parent_id = parent_id
                    block.save()
                num_created += 1
                if verbose:
                    print >> sys.stderr, 'Created block %s' % block
        return num_created
```

Output:

```
'GRAND-CH\xcaNE, COUR DU'
Looking at block GRAND-CH�NE, COUR DU
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "../blocks_ottawa.py", line 144, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "../blocks_ottawa.py", line 139, in main
    num_created = esri.save(options.verbose)
  File "../blocks_ottawa.py", line 114, in save
    block.save()
  File "/home/chris/openblock/src/django/django/db/models/base.py", line 434, in save
    self.save_base(using=using, force_insert=force_insert, force_update=force_update)
  File "/home/chris/openblock/src/django/django/db/models/base.py", line 527, in save_base
    result = manager._insert(values, return_id=update_pk, using=using)
  File "/home/chris/openblock/src/django/django/db/models/manager.py", line 195, in _insert
    return insert_query(self.model, values, **kwargs)
  File "/home/chris/openblock/src/django/django/db/models/query.py", line 1479, in insert_query
    return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(return_id)
  File "/home/chris/openblock/src/django/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 783, in execute_sql
    cursor = super(SQLInsertCompiler, self).execute_sql(None)
  File "/home/chris/openblock/src/django/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 727, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/chris/openblock/src/django/django/db/backends/util.py", line 15, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/chris/openblock/src/django/django/db/backends/postgresql_psycopg2/base.py", line 44, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(query, args)

django.db.utils.DatabaseError: invalid byte sequence for encoding "UTF8": 0xca4e
HINT:  This error can also happen if the byte sequence does not match the encoding expected by the server, which is controlled by "client_encoding".
```

Comment: No, you get "Unicode not supported" because his "solution" is producing Unicode and you are feeding it to something that doesn't like it. Don't do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

More information please. What platform - Windows / Linux / ???

What version of Python?

If you are running Windows, your encoding is much more likely to be `cp1252` or similar than `ISO-8859-1`. It's definitely not `UTF-8`.

You will need to: (1) Find out what your input data is encoded with. Try `cp1252`; it's the usual suspect. (2) decode your data into unicode (3) encode it into UTF-8.

How are you getting the data out of your ESRI shapefile? Show your code. Show the full traceback and error message. To avoid visual problems (it's E-grave! no, it's E-acute!) `print repr(the_suspect_data)` and copy/paste the result into an edit of your question. Go easy on the bold type.

Comment: @Chris: Ottawa -> `cp1252`. You should look at the docs for `django.contrib.gis.gdal.DataSource` to see if it mentions encoding anywhere. In any case, if you want/need to have the data in UTF-8 to put it in the database, you need to do `esri_text.decode('whatever').encode('utf8')` somehow (maybe two steps).

Comment: I did - nothing in the docs about encoding, but the decode then encode worked great! Thanks so much! Still lots to wrap my head around in the encoding world.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the data isn't being sent as UTF-8... so check the client_encoding parameter in your DB session matches your data, or translate it to UTF-8/Unicode within Python when reading the file.

You can change the DB session's client encoding using "SET client_encoding = 'ISO-8859-1'" or similar. 0xca isn't E-with-grave in Latin1, though, so I'm not sure which character encoding your file is in?

Comment: Every other string being looped through that doesn't have any accented characters throws a "decoding Unicode is not supported
" error, which from what I can tell happens if the string is already unicode. So it would seem that that character or strings containing accents are the issue?

Comment: where exactly is that error thrown from? I'm not really familiar with Python, but it doesn't sound like a PostgreSQL error that I remember.

Comment: 0xca is E-with-circumflex in ISO-8859-1 btw, so that makes sense. Seriously, just changing the client_encoding setting for your db session should work, essentially by passing the buck for decoding bytes to characters onto the database.

Answer (score -3):

You can try something like:

`uString = unicode(item.field, "utf-8")`

See http://evanjones.ca/python-utf8.html for more details about Unicode and Python.

Comment: You are just assuming he is hardcoding wevery string he is dumping in the database inside teh python source code? That is the only caise using this would work.

Comment: The assumption was that you could assign the values into an object or list. Without knowing where the data was coming from it wasn't worth abstracting beyond the individual string.

Comment: In this case I think I'd be fine actually doing it just for an individual string. Sorry I didn't include the code from the start.

Comment: @Chris: NO YOU WON'T BE FINE JUST DOING IT FOR AN INDIVIDUAL STRING. DOING IT IS AN UTTER NONSENSE.

Comment: @John, I actually meant encoding it much the way you indicated above in your comment... not manually for each string.